# How to add dependencies in android library module

Tags: android, gradle, module, dependencies

I am creating a new project, in that project I am adding my own created library as a library module, but after adding them the dependencies are not able to access from my application class and even not working in library module.

**First case:** 
Library Module - Application class (used for initializing firebase analytics, glide, etc)

```
In the above case I am not able to use Application class in App Module, because for a single project one Application class is required
```

**Second Case:** If I am initializing Firebase and Glide etc in App module, Application class by removing library module Application class. Then I need to add app module dependency in library module.

```
 In the above case  If I am doing that circular dependency is coming.
```

So Please help me how to resolve this.

Regards

Comment: follow this steps .https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html.. OR http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. It is very easy to create aar file by following document, After integrating aar in to my app module as a dependency I have issues to build app. But Finally I resolved in such a way : 1. Library Module using Application class and my app module extends that Application class.  2. Adding Library dependencies from gradle in to app module gradle file. Finally it is working. Thanks for support

Comment: If Your Problem Solved You Post Ans To your Own Question . IT Will Help Others As well..

Comment: Hi, It is solved, I am extending library module application class to app module application class. so in my project library and app modules are working with application class